# Solutions of the equation of the form $\sin(x)=\sin(y)$

Tags: trigonometry

Why does the equation " $\sin(x)=\sin(y)$" have solutions $x=y+2k \pi$ and $x=(\pi-y)+2k\pi$ ? 
For instance: 
if  $\sin(30)=\sin(150)$, then we say $30=150+2k\pi$ but how come $30=510=870=$…?

Comment: Use radians not degrees.

Answer (score 2):

That's because $\sin 30 \neq \sin 150$. We do have $\sin 30^\circ = \sin 150^\circ$, though, but that's a totally different story. In other words, you're mixing radians and degrees.

The degree-ifyed statement is that if $\sin x = \sin y$ then we have
$$
x = y + k\cdot 360^\circ \quad \text{or}\quad x = 180^\circ - y + k\cdot 360^\circ
$$
"$30=510=870=$" is outright false, although it is true that $\sin 30^\circ = \sin 510^\circ$ and $\sin 30^\circ = \sin 870^\circ$, because
$$
510^\circ = 180^\circ - 30^\circ + 360^\circ
$$
and
$$
870^\circ = 180^\circ - 30^\circ + 2\cdot 360^\circ
$$
as per the above.

Comment: But how can we say 30 degrees (or pi/6 radians) is equal to 510 degrees (or 2pi+(pi/6) ? How can 30 be equal to 510? They are obvously different quantities.

Comment: @user483206 Yes, they are different quantities. They aren't equal at all. How is this a problem? (Also, $510^\circ$ isn't $2\pi + \frac\pi6$, it's $2\pi + \frac{5\pi}6$.)

Comment: If we have sin(x)=sin(y) then we say that we have solutions in the form of x=y+2kπ and x=(π−y)+2kπ , ignoring the sine function in front. But this yields to the absurd result such as 30=510, doesn't it?

Comment: @user483206 No, $\sin 30^\circ = \sin 510^\circ$ yields $30^\circ = (180^\circ - 510^\circ) + 1\cdot 360^\circ$.

Comment: @user483206  The equation $\sin\theta = \sin\varphi$ is satisfied when the points where the terminal sides of angles $\theta$ and $\varphi$ have the same $y$-coordinates.  There are two points on the unit circle where the $y$-coordinate is equal to $\frac{1}{2}$.  They are $(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}, \frac{1}{2})$ and $(-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}, \frac{1}{2})$.  The first corresponds to the angles $\frac{\pi}{6} + 2k\pi, k \in \mathbb{Z}$.  The second corresponds to the angles $\frac{5\pi}{6} + 2k\pi, k \in \mathbb{Z}$.  They have the same sine values, but the angles do not need to be equal.

Answer (score 0):

If $ \sin y = \sin x $ then for $n=-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4.. $

$$ y = n \,180^{\circ} +  (-1)^ n \cdot  x $$